# How to connect 2.2 tft screen tod raspberry pi 2 model b?

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, chipset, raspbian-wheezy

hi i buy a raspberry 2 Model b with a TFT screen 2.2 and I can not configure it to use it as a display. 
Can you help me on how to wiring to the gpio and how to configure the driver to see.?
Sorry for my English
***I´m tried with notro´s kernel but only gets a whites scren.***

I tell you in detail the components I am using:

**Raspberry pi 2 model B v 1.1
Screen: TFT LCD ( Adafruit  Chip Set ILI9341 or compatible) 2.2" TFT LCD
OS: 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie**

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I follow this tutorials: http://blog.riyas.org/2014/07/quickly-test-il9341-22-inch-22-spi-tft-raspbmc-fbtft.html

http://www.raspberrypirobot.com/2-2-tft-lcd-display-240x320-for-raspberrypi 

But not work for me.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.